# How to set and retrieve ArrayList when used as a member variable of another object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have following code:

```
 public class Address {

    private String city;

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
```

And I have another class `User` with `ArrayList<Address>` as member variable as follows.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class User {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Address> listOfAddresses ;

    public ArrayList<Address> getListOfAddresses() {
        return listOfAddresses;
    }

    public void setListOfAddresses(ArrayList<Address> listOfAddresses) {
        this.listOfAddresses = listOfAddresses;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

And in the class with the main method, I have created user object which has two member variable such as name and `listofAddresses`. Now, I need some guidance about how to set value for `listOfAddresses` using user object. And also how to retrieve using user object.

My main class looks like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayImpl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("First User");

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setCity("Melbourne");

        user.setListOfAddresses(address);   

    }

}
```

And I'm getting error at the `user.setListofAddressess(address)` as:

> The method setListOfAddresses(ArrayList) in the type User is
>   not applicable for the arguments (Address)

My understanding is that listOfAddresses is an ArrayList of type `Address` and thus I'm trying to use setter method of `listOfAddresses` member variable to set it's value.

Can somebody please help me how to set `listOfAddresses` and retrieve using `user` object.

Comment: You're calling `setListOfAddresses` with a *single* address. That's not going to work - you'd have to call it with a list of addresses. Or, better, change your method to `addAddress`.

Comment: A small advice: I wouldn't just assign ArrayList received from external world, as it's mutable and can be changed without you noticing that. Better take a look at ArraysList#addAll method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set variable of type 'address' in user object but you are supposed to set an object of type ArrayList their.

```
User user = new User();

ArrayList<Address> ar=new ArrayList<>();
Address ad1=new Address();
ad1.setCity("Melbourne");
ar.add(ad1);

user.setListOfAddresses(ar);
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped understanding. Can you also explain how to retrieve the address using getListOfAddresses()?

Comment: `ArrayList<Address> ar=user.getListOfAddresses();     for(int i=0;i<ar.size();i++){                  Address ad=ar.get(i);   
//do something by getting city name like this ad.getCity(); }`

Answer (score 1):

You have primarily two options:

**Ugly Way**
You retrieve the current list of addresses by calling the Getter, then adding your new address, then calling the Setter with your new list:

```
List<Address> addresses = user.getListOfAddresses();
addresses.add(address);
user.setListOfAddresses(addresses);
```

**The smart and cool way**
Your class `User` provides delegates to add and remove Addresses. For this, add methods for your purposes in your `User` class:

```
public void addAddress(Address a) {
    this.listOfAddresses.add(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method definition for `setListOfAddresses` in User class takes as argument an object of type `ArrayList<Address>`, but in your main you're trying to pass it an instance of Address.

This is the right approach:

```
ArrayList<Address> addrList = user.getListOfAddresses(); 
if (addrList == null) { 
   //If it's the first address you insert, you have to initialize the ArrayList
   addrList = new ArrayList<Address>();
}
addrList.add(address);
```

Then to retrieve each address i straightforward:

```
ArrayList<Address> addrList = user.getListOfAddresses();
for (Address a : addrList) {
   //do something with a....
}
```